# Level 2 question: orders filled at best offer price not moving the the size of best offer

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, shorting-securities, level-2-quotes

1. Suppose I have a best offer on Level 2: 200 shares at $2.  If I place a bid for 100 shares at $2, I would expect level 2 to show the best offer to be 100 shares at $2 after my order is filled. But I don't see that happening. What could be the reason?
2. Sometimes I notice that if I place an order for 100 shares at $2 with best offer for 200 shares at $2, it gets filled at a price lower than $2 - like $1.75. This happens even though the best offer has not changed.

I assume that shorting has something to do with this, but I would like to understand the mechanics.

Comment: Possibilities: hidden orders, or traders that are much faster than you.

Comment: 1) A hidden order hides the true size of an order.   They are invisible on Level Two.  2) No idea why you're filled at a lower price

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 2:

- could be your broker is filling it before even transmitting it, because he’s got a matching order inhouse (or in his own interest). There is nothing to complain about as you get a better-than-expected price.
- could also be someone has a combined limit order, for example “sell 100 *and* buy a call”, and it ended up giving a better price.